# Replacing pairs of variables in a file

Tags: python

I working on a problem and my goal is to replace variables in the file  and the name of the files. 
The issue is that I have to change a couple of variables at the same time for all combinations (Generally 24 combinations).

I know how to create of all combinations of strings, but I want to put lists inside and iterate over them.

```
a = [ 'distance', 'T1', 'T2', 'gamma' ]
new_list = list(itertools.permutations(a, 2))
```

I created the function to pass my values:

```
def replace_variables(distance ='0', T1 ='0', T2 = '0', gamma = '0'):
        template_new = template.replace('*distance*', distance).replace('*T1*', T1).replace('*T2*', T2).replace('*gamma*', gamma)
        input_file = input_name.replace('one','T1'+T1).replace('two','T2'+T2).replace('phi','PHI'+Phi).replace('distance','R'+distance)

        return template_new, input_file
```

when I call that function I can pass only names of variables.

```
for i in new_list:
        elem1 = i[0]
        elem2 = i[1]
        template_new, input_file =replace_variables(elem1, elem2)
        print input_file
```

Though I need to use lists:

```
distance = ['-3','+3']
T1 = ['-3', '+3']
T2 = ['-3', '+3']
gamma = ['-3', '+3']
```

And for each pair of variables change values in a file and a name of file such as:

original file: `name_file_R_T1_T2_gamma.txt`

will be replaced by:

```
name_file_3_3_0_0.txt, name_file_3_-3_0_0.txt,  name_file_-3_3_0_0.txt,
name_file_3_3_0_0.txt, name_file_3_0_3_0.txt, name_file_3_0_-3_0.txt,
```

and so forth.

The original template looks like:

```
template = """
 R              =         3.0 *distance* cm
 THETA1         =         60. *T1*  degree
 THETA2         =         2.0  *T2* degree
 GAMMA          =         0 *gamma* degree
"""
```

and I want to obtain:

```
template = """     
     R              =         3.0 +3 cm
     THETA1         =         60. +3  degree
     THETA2         =         2.0  +0 degree
     GAMMA          =         0 +0 degree

"""
```

and so forth

Comment: Your post is unclear.   Perhaps if you provide more information about your templates.

Comment: so `input_name = "name_file_R_T1_T2_gamma.txt"`? you replace the text `"one", "two", "phi", "distance"` so I'd expect the name of the file to be unchanged, also I don't understand how you came about `"name_file_-3_3_0_0.txt"` where did the `-3` come from?  please edit to clarify your question.

Comment: I just added more information about my template.

Answer (score 0):

I think I almost tackled the above problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import itertools
import copy

def replace_variables(i, distance ='0', T1 ='0', T2 = '0', gamma = '0' ):
        k_  = copy.deepcopy(i)
        k_[0][0] = '-2'
        k_[1][0] = '2'
        template_new = template.replace('*distance*', distance).replace('*T1*', T1).replace('*T2*', T2).replace('*gamma*', gamma)
        input_file = input_name.replace('one','T1'+T1).replace('two','T2'+T2).replace('gamma','gamma'+gamma).replace('distance','R'+distance)

     f = open(template_new, 'w')
     f.write(template_new)
     f.close()


input_name = 'name_file_distance_T1_T2_gamma.txt'

template = """
  R              =         3.0 *distance* cm
 THETA1         =         60. *T1*  degree
 THETA2         =         2.0  *T2* degree
 GAMMA          =         0 *gamma* degree
"""

a = [['distance','+2','-2'], ['T1','+2','-2'], ['T2','+2','-2'], ['gamma','+2','-2']]
new_list = list(itertools.permutations(a, 2))

for i in new_list:
      replace_variables(i, x, y)
```

Though I faced 2 problems:

1) My code does not change values of variables (apart from default ones) in the replace_variables function and I'm getting: 
name_file_Rdistance_T1T1_T20_gamma0.txt, and so on
I think because of default arguments passed to the function.

2) My function does not create a separated files.